# Cronjob and Mavericks sleep mode

Tags: cron, osx-mavericks

I've installed the new Mavericks OS on my mac and the sleep mode seems to stop everything including cronjobs, logmein service, etc.

Do you guys have the same issue? How could we fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a cron job that sends out an email under a certain condition and I get the email (sent to another machine) while my Mac (Mavericks) is asleep.  That's contrary to what I'm seeing here.  The weird thing is that doesn't happen very often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer here : https://superuser.com/questions/14836/crontab-to-wake-osx-from-sleep

My point is that Mountain Lion was still running cron jobs while asleep with default energy saver configuration, but Mavericks doesn't anymore (and without installing anything like anacron, etc.)

If someone find out how Mountain Lion was doing so, I'd be interested. Thanks.